# Mongoose schema -- populations in separate field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm working a codebase with lots of code directly referencing documents by id

for example

```
user : {
user_id,
username,
...}
```

And there are tons of places that directly reference user.user_id.

I'm trying to make a mongoose.js population on the user_id field on a separate document, but it will only let me specify it like this

```
user_id : { type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'User' }
```

Seeing as how I've already used user_id, how can I make a related population with a different name?  It seems trivial that it could be mapped to users regardless of being name, but I don't see a way to do it.

it'd be great if I could just do

```
users: { type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'User', field : 'user_id' }
```

But it seems no one is trying to do this, nor has anyone managed to do it.